# Trying to delete file from Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

Please,
How can I delete my file on Google workspace from google cloud service account?

my architecture is :

Local machine : **executing scripting.**
service account from Google cloud; **xxxxxx@myproject-monitoring.iam.gserviceaccount.com** with **editor** permission.
google drive API - >** activated**

By when I trying to delete some files from Google drive folder about this service account, I have *permission denied. *

How can I solve this problem?

**# I reviewed all configuration from scenario , and did the test with users account, and I can see this working but if I trying with the service account, I  have permission denied. **